# How can I describe the iterated expectation $E_X(E_{X,Z}(E(Y\mid X,Z)\mid X)) = E(Y)$ using a sampling process?

Tags: probability, statistics

I currently have a conditional expectation I would like to describe using a sampling process.

$$
E_X(E_{X,Z}(E(Y\mid X,Z)\mid X)) = E(Y)
$$

Specifically, I would like to suppose that $Y$ is a discrete random variable I am trying to estimate, and that $X,Z$ are also discrete random variables.

I would like to understand how I can describe the above using a sampling procedure that can result in unbiased estimates of $E(Y)$.

For example, I suppose that from the pool of observations for which I have $X,Z$, I randomly draw observations $X=x,Z=z$. Then, I compute the average of $Y$ at levels of $X=x,Z=z$. This appears to give unbiased estimates for

$$
E(Y)
$$

over $X,Z$. However, in the above equation I have a conditional on $X$ on the outside, which is akin to saying I am resorting to a "cruder" measure on the joint space of $(Y,X,Z)$ by estimating over levels of $X$. For this, I am unsure how to think of the sampling process.

Could someone give any tips as to how the above equation plays out in sampling? Thank you.

Comment: If you can compute E(Y|X,Z) then just sample many (X,Z) and given these values compute the previous quantity and average them. This is a consistent estimate of E(Y). However if E(Y|X,Z) must be estimated as well (sample many Y's given X,Z and average), it is not clear what the asymptotics are since we have essentially nested averages.

Comment: @JamesYang Thanks, how would you imagine sampling $E(E(Y\mid X, Z)\mid X)$? Would this just be 1) Sampling a value of $X$, fixing it, then sampling many times over repeated draws of $Z$? As in, like a double loop of fixing $X$, then looping over many $Z$, then redo-ing with a new $X$?